# Vanishing seq_len in attention-based BiLSTM

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, attention-model

I'm studying several implementations of **self attention-based BiLSTM** and I don't understand why in each of them the input and output size are different. In particular I refer to the following codes taken from different implementations:

Implementation [1](https://github.com/littleflow3r/attention-bilstm-for-relation-classification/blob/master/model.py) e [2](https://github.com/zhijing-jin/pytorch_RelationExtraction_AttentionBiLSTM/blob/master/model.py)

```
 def attnetwork(self, encoder_out, final_hidden):
        # encoder_out shape = (batch_size, seq_len, n_hidden)
        # final_hidden shape = (1, batch_size, n_hidden)
        hidden = final_hidden.squeeze(0)  
        attn_weights = torch.bmm(encoder_out, hidden.unsqueeze(2)).squeeze(2)
        soft_attn_weights = F.softmax(attn_weights, 1)
        new_hidden = torch.bmm(encoder_out.transpose(1,2), soft_attn_weights.unsqueeze(2)).squeeze(2)
        return new_hidden # shape = (batch_size, n_hidden)
```

As you can see this implementation takes as input two vectors of dimension `(batch_size, seq_len, n_hidden)` and `(1, batch_size, n_hidden)`, respectively, and returns a vector of dimensions `(batch_size, n_hidden)` . But where is the dimension relative to `seq_len`? I need to have an output vector equal to the input one (i.e `(batch_size, seq_len, n_hidden)`).

Another [implementation](https://www.programmersought.com/article/68725413549/) where the input size does not match the output size:

```
def attention(self,H):
        M = torch.tanh(H) # Non-linear transformation size:(batch_size, hidden_dim, seq_len)
        a = F.softmax(torch.bmm(self.att_weight,M),dim=2) # a.Size : (batch_size,1,seq_len)
        a = torch.transpose(a,1,2) # (batch_size,seq_len,1)
        return torch.bmm(H,a) # (batch_size,hidden_dim,1)
```

Another [implementation](https://github.com/wabyking/TextClassificationBenchmark/blob/master/models/LSTMwithAttention.py) with the same problem:

```
def attention(self, rnn_out, state):
        merged_state = torch.cat([s for s in state],1)
        merged_state = merged_state.squeeze(0).unsqueeze(2)
        # (batch, seq_len, cell_size) * (batch, cell_size, 1) = (batch, seq_len, 1)
        weights = torch.bmm(rnn_out, merged_state)
        weights = torch.nn.functional.softmax(weights.squeeze(2)).unsqueeze(2)
        # (batch, cell_size, seq_len) * (batch, seq_len, 1) = (batch, cell_size, 1)
        return torch.bmm(torch.transpose(rnn_out, 1, 2), weights).squeeze(2)
```

How could one do to output a tensor of the same size as the input one without "breaking" the self attention mechanism?

Thank you!

EDIT:
The forward function I have to use is this:

```
def forward(self, x, x_len):
        x = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(x, x_len, batch_first=True)
        out1, (h_n, c_n) = self.lstm1(x)
        # out1 = (seq_len, batch, num_directions * hidden_size)
        # h_n = (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size)
        x, lengths = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(out1, batch_first=True)
        x, att1 = self.atten1(x, lengths)  # skip connect
        return x
```

the final `x` in `return x` I absolutely need it to have the shape `(batch_size, seq_len, hidden_state)` (obv also in another order so that a `transpose` is enough to fix it).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, what an attention-based model does is :

1. Calculate some relationships between decoder hidden states and
   encoder outputs.
2. Take softmax to get the attention distribution.
3. Take a weighted sum of the encoder output to get the attention output.

And a Seq2seq model act like:

1. Pass your sequences e.g., an sentence through an encoder, get a encoder output and a hidden layer ,use this hidden layer to initialize your decoder.
2. Calculate your attention model by initial decoder hidden states and encoder outputs.
3. Feed your decoder with a start character e.g.,  ,get a single character as output and a new hidden state, then use your attention model to calculate a new output.
4. Feed your decoder with a single-character input (defined on your own, may depend on a teacher-force ratio) and attention output (may concatenate attention output with decoder hidden state or something else), then you get a new character.
5. Loop 4 to get your predict sequence character by character.

You may have a look at this (from page 59):
http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/slides/cs224n-2021-lecture07-nmt.pdf

Every time a character sent to your LSTM decoder, it will output a new character, and its hidden states will update to another value. The key is, hidden states keep changing.

So a (batch_size,hidden_dim,1) attention output is reasonable, since you should give a character to your model, use a corresponding attention output to help predicting next character, then get a new hidden state and get a new attention output and so on. You may not give a whole sequence to your LSTM decoder, you can't use any hidden states under that circumstance.

Comment: ok I understand your reasoning. We skip the seq2seq discourse because I only have one bilstm to which to apply a self-attention (if you really want, it's like the self-attention used in the encoder). If the output is ```(batch_size, hidden_dim, 1)``` how could I use it for the whole sequence? How could I do, in practice, to "repeat" this mechanism for a number of times equal to ```seq_len```?

Comment: When training LSTM it is necessary to group the sequences of variable length. For example: if the length of the sequences in a batch of size 8 is [4,6,8,5,4,3,7,8], I have to somehow keep track of the seq_len, even while applying attention, but i don't understand how.

Comment: Oh you are asking about self-attention... Self-attention is a mechanism that totally different from the code you pasted above. Please have a google of it.

Comment: Ok, but the point is the same. Please see this gist which I am trying to use: https://gist.github.com/cbaziotis/94e53bdd6e4852756e0395560ff38aa4

The return value of representation is ```(batch_size, n_hiddden)```, while that of scores is ```(batch_size, seq_len)```, but what I need is always an output tensor with shape ```(batch_size, seq_len, n_hidden)```. I hope I have explained and in the meantime thanks for the help.

Comment: In your opinion (referring to the gist above) is it right to output ```weighted``` directly instead of ```representations```? (using ```weighted``` for the rest of the training)